# How to add deployment message parameter with CloudBees Deployer plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

Is there a way to give a custom message to the deployment with the Cloudbees Deployer plugin? We are used to putting the git version to the deployment so that it's easier to see which version we have running at run@cloud.

We've tried doing the deployment with the bees maven plugin and there it's possible to get the message parameter set from a build parameter. It just would be nice to be able to use the plugin instead of having to mess with the maven plugin, which is easier to get wrong in the configuration phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was not available prior to version [4.4 of the CloudBees Deployer plugin](http://release-notes.cloudbees.com/release/CloudBees+Deployer+Plugin/4.4).

Version 4.4 adds the ability to configure the description in the "Advanced" button:

[image: Application configuration with the Advanced button expanded]

The default value for this field is `${JOB_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER}` so as to retain the previous behaviour.

The field supports all the usual Jenkins Environment token macro expansion, so you probably want to set it to something like `${GIT_COMMIT}` or maybe `${GIT_COMMIT} ${JOB_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER}`. In any case the standard token macros should provide the flexibility you require.

Note: If you are using DEV@cloud, and the Jenkins has a pre-4.4 version of the plugin you will have to wait until after `2013-04-15T15:00Z` and restart your Jenkins instance to pick up the newer version of the plugin.

Note: If you are using the CloudBees Deployer plugin via the [CloudBees Free Enterprise Plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Free+Enterprise+Plugins) route, you will have to force the update center metadata to update or wait until after `2013-04-16T12:30Z` to see the update in the list of plugins.